# Vectorized function to count numbers in an array when a number is a specified power

Tags: c++, math, simd, counting, avx2

I am attempting to vectorize this fairly expensive function (Scaler Now working!):

```
template<typename N, typename POW>
inline constexpr bool isPower(const N n, const POW p) noexcept
{
    double x = std::log(static_cast<double>(n)) / std::log(static_cast<double>(p));

    return (x - std::trunc(x)) < 0.000001;
}//End of isPower
```

Here's what I have so far (for 32-bit int only):

```
 template<typename RETURN_T>
 inline RETURN_T count_powers_of(const std::vector<int32_t>& arr, const int32_t power)
 {
      RETURN_T cnt = 0;
      
      const __m256 _MAGIC = _mm256_set1_ps(0.000001f);
      const __m256 _POWER_D = _mm256_set1_ps(static_cast<float>(para));

      const __m256 LOG_OF_POWER = _mm256_log_ps(_POWER_D);

      __m256i _count = _mm256_setzero_si256();
      __m256i _N_INT = _mm256_setzero_si256();
      __m256 _N_DBL = _mm256_setzero_ps();
      __m256 LOG_OF_N = _mm256_setzero_ps();
      __m256 DIVIDE_LOG = _mm256_setzero_ps();
      __m256 TRUNCATED = _mm256_setzero_ps();

      __m256 CMP_MASK = _mm256_setzero_ps();
                                                  
      for (size_t i = 0uz; (i + 8uz) < end; i += 8uz)
      {
           //Set Values
           _N_INT = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*) &arr[i]);
           _N_DBL = _mm256_cvtepi32_ps(_N_INT);
                            
           LOG_OF_N = _mm256_log_ps(_N_DBL);

           DIVIDE_LOG = _mm256_div_ps(LOG_OF_N, LOG_OF_POWER);

           TRUNCATED = _mm256_sub_ps(DIVIDE_LOG, _mm256_trunc_ps(DIVIDE_LOG));

           CMP_MASK = _mm256_cmp_ps(TRUNCATED, _MAGIC, _CMP_LT_OQ);

           _count = _mm256_sub_epi32(_count, _mm256_castps_si256(CMP_MASK));
      }//End for

     cnt = static_cast<RETURN_T>(util::_mm256_sum_epi32(_count));
 }//End of count_powers_of
```

The scaler version runs in about 14.1 seconds.
The scaler version called from std::count_if with par_unseq runs in 4.5 seconds.

**The vectorized version runs in just 155 milliseconds but produces the wrong result. Albeit vastly closer now.**

Testing:

```
 int64_t count = 0;
 for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
 {              
    if (isPower(vec[i], 4))
    {
        ++count;
    }//End if
}//End for

std::cout << "Counted " << count << " powers of 4.\n";//produces 4,996,215 powers of 4 in a vector of 1 billion 32-bit ints consisting of a uniform distribution of 0 to 1000

std::cout << "Counted " << count_powers_of<int32_t>(vec, 4) << " powers of 4.\n";//produces 4,996,865 powers of 4 on the same array
```

This new vastly simplified code often produces results that are either slightly off the correct number of powers found (usually higher). I think the problem is my reinterpret cast from __m256 to _m256i but when I try use a conversation (with floor) instead I get a number that's way off (in the billions again).

It could also be this sum function (based off of code by @PeterCordes ):

```
 inline uint32_t _mm_sum_epi32(__m128i& x)
{
    __m128i hi64 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(x, x);           
    __m128i sum64 = _mm_add_epi32(hi64, x);
    __m128i hi32 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(sum64, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 3, 0, 1));
    __m128i sum32 = _mm_add_epi32(sum64, hi32);
    return _mm_cvtsi128_si32(sum32);
}

 inline uint32_t _mm256_sum_epi32(__m256i& v)
{
    __m128i sum128 = _mm_add_epi32(
        _mm256_castsi256_si128(v),
        _mm256_extracti128_si256(v, 1));
    return _mm_sum_epi32(sum128);
}
```

I know this has got to be a floating-point precision/comparison issue; Is there a better way to approach this?

Thanks for all your insights and suggestions thus far.

Comment: I'm not a doctor, but this seems a little much. `std::count_if` seems to me like it'd work, and could look pretty nice with the cleanup "`if(_) return true; else return false;` to `return _;`". That being said, something you might try is passing a few vectors with all the entries set to the same number, and figuring out which inputs cause the disagreement.

Comment: @RShields I already tried std::count_if with par_unseq to boot and that version still takes 2.5 times longer than my vectorized version. I will try your second suggestion though.

Comment: How heavily have you debugged this?  Is your vector size a multiple of 8?  Did you mean to test `(i + 7uz) < end` instead of `(i + 8uz) < end`?

Comment: Side-note: as a matter of style, don't comment every close-brace.  It makes the code way harder to read.  You're already using indentation correctly, which should be enough.

Comment: @paddy AVX Registers are 256 bits (32 bytes) long enough space for 8 32-bit integers, thus to use them you load 8 at a time.

Comment: Yes, therefore an iteration loads 7 more than scalar code would, so `i < end-7` is appropriate to check if we should start a new iteration, or I guess maybe `(i+7) < end` although that creates more work that isn't loop-invariant.

Comment: I was talking about your `std::vector` size.  The loop is clearly moving in steps of 8, but if `end` is a one-past-the-end index then you have an off-by-one error in the loop condition which will ignore the last 8 values.  And if the size is not a multiple of 8, you will also not handle the last `size % 8` values.

Comment: @paddy I've got a separate loop to continue where the AVX version left off, I just didn't want to repeat the same code here. In anycase if I were missing data, the resulting count would surely be lower not higher.

Comment: This seems to depend on there being no floating-point rounding error.  You do `d == (N)d` which (if N is an integral type) checks that the ratio of two logs is an exact integer; even 1 bit in the mantissa will make it unequal.  Hardly surprising that a different `log` implementation would give different results, if one has different rounding error.

Comment: Also, that `d == (N)d` is done before checking if `N` is a floating-point type, so apparently you intend to support that?  But if N=double, `d == (double)d` is always true (except for NaN or Infinity).  Probably you want `int` there; an int can hold the log of any double.  (The function fails for `pow = 1`; that would divide by log(1) = zero and give `d=Inf`, so the largest valid d is about log2(DBL_MAX) ~= 1024.  i.e. the max value of the 11-bit signed exponent field in a [`double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).  `int` is fine even for extended-prec.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Hmm. Yeah, I'll look into that. How's my AVX2 code look? Again sorry for the naming convention (or lack there of).

Comment: BTW, you might want to special-case integer N, power-of-2 pow.  That can go vastly vaster by checking that `n` has a single bit set (`n & (n-1) == 0`) and that it's at a valid position.  (e.g. for pow=4, `n & 0b...10101010 != 0`).  You can construct the constant by multiplying and adding.

Comment: Taking logs and dividing are quite slow; it might be faster to brute-force check 32-bit integers one at a time against the 32 or fewer possible powers that fit in an int32_t.  (e.g. broadcast-load, 4x `vpcmpeqd` / `vpsubd` into multiple accumulators.)  That only handles 1 input element per vector instead of 4 doubles, but I could see that running more than 4x the throughput per iteration of what you're doing now, especially with very slow stuff like `_mm256_rem_epi32` integer division going on, on top of FP logs and division.  Also, this has the advantage of no rounding error.

Comment: @PeterCordes OK, but my problem with my AVX code is not that it's too slow (it actually runs 5 times faster than the loop and 3.5 times faster than std::count_if par_unseq), it's that it produces the incorrect results. It finds 6-10 billion powers of 4 on array of only 1 billion elements.

Comment: Wait a minute, `_mm256_rem_epi32` is used with a constant divisor of `2`.  Integer mod 2 is just `n & 1`.  Or if you need to handle negative remainders, you can use the tricks compilers use to implement `int % 2`:  https://godbolt.org/z/b89eWqEzK

Comment: Like I said in [an early comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71375793/vectorized-function-to-count-numbers-in-an-array-when-a-number-is-a-specified-po#comment126161330_71375793), FP rounding error probably makes this a non-starter.  That may be unfixable.  I'd certainly want a implementation that tested with pure integer code to check against.

Comment: @PeterCordes Awe crap, So unless I write a log function that works exactly like SVML's log function, I won't have a valid comparison? Well thanks for all your suggestions I'm going to bed now, I have to be up at 5 AM tomorrow.

Comment: Or maybe I'm misunderstanding the scalar algorithm.  It's using `d = floor(log_p(n))`, but it's also doing `return d == (N)d;`.  I don't see how that works.  I thought you were looking for exact powers, not just ones whose integer part has some value.  If you were just looking for numbers from `4**5` through `4**6`, you'd have a range-check `(x>=a && x<b)` where `a` and `b` are loop-invariant.

Comment: @dave_thenerd: It's not about "valid comparison" or not, it's about whether correctness is even possible *at all*, especially when you're taking log_base_e with the inherent FP rounding error in that an `ln(abs(p))`.  Vectorizing a broken algorithm probably isn't useful, although sure if you did want to see if you vectorized it correctly, you'd need equivalent log functions.

Comment: I just tried your scalar version for a testcase like `return isPower(5, 4)` to ask if 5 is a power of 4.  It returns true: https://godbolt.org/z/aMT94ro6o .  So yeah, your code is super broken, and is in fact only checking that `n>0` or something.

Comment: Checking `if (d == (N)d)` is almost pointless if you `floor`-ed `d` before that. You could do `d = std::log(std::abs(n)) /std::log(std::abs(p));` and then check if `floor(d) == d` but that would also rely on having no rounding errors. For integers, I'd rather do some kind of binary search, i.e., raise your base to powers of 2, 4, 8, 16; then if `n > p^16` check if it is also larger then `p^24` otherwise check if it is larger than `p^8` and so on (with `^` meaning the power not the xor-operator).

Comment: A more sensible unit-test would be to non-random: Check all powers in a loop to make sure they're all true, like `x *= base;`, and count how many powers there are <= n.   Then check *all* numbers from 0..n in a loop, once each to verify the right total.  If both those checks succeed, that means it returned false in all the cases it should have, otherwise the count would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A more sensible unit-test would be to non-random: Check all powers in a loop to make sure they're all true, like `x *= base;`, and count how many powers there are <= n.   Then check *all* numbers from 0..n in a loop, once each to verify the right total.  If both those checks succeed, that means it returned false in all the cases it should have, otherwise the count would be wrong.

---

#### Re: the original version:

This seems to depend on there being no floating-point rounding error. You do `d == (N)d` which (if N is an integral type) checks that the ratio of two logs is an exact integer; even 1 bit in the mantissa will make it unequal. Hardly surprising that a different log implementation would give different results, if one has different rounding error.

Except your scalar code at least is even more broken because it takes `d = floor(log ratio)` so it's already always an exact integer.

I just tried your scalar version for a testcase like `return isPower(5, 4)` to ask if 5 is a power of 4.  It returns true: https://godbolt.org/z/aMT94ro6o .  So yeah, your code is super broken, and is in fact only checking that `n>0` or something.  **That would explain why 999 of 1000 of your "random" inputs from 0..999 were counted as powers of 4, which is obviously super broken.**

I think it's impossible to achieve correctness with your FP log ratio idea: FP rounding error means you can't expect exact equality, but allowing a range would probably let in non-exact powers.

---

You might want to special-case integral `N`, power-of-2 `pow`. That can go vastly vaster by checking that `n` has a single bit set (`n & (n-1) == 0`) and that it's at a valid position. (e.g. for `pow=4`, `n & 0b...10101010 != 0`). You can construct the constant by multiplying and adding until overflow or something.  Or 32/pow times?  Anyway, one psubd/pand/pcmpeqd, pand/pcmpeqd, and pand/psubd per 8 elements, with maybe some room to optimize  that further.

Otherwise, in the general case, you can brute-force check 32-bit integers one at a time against the 32 or fewer possible powers that fit in an int32_t. e.g. broadcast-load, 4x `vpcmpeqd` / `vpsubd` into multiple accumulators.  (The smallest possible base, `2`, can have exponents up to 2^31` and still fit in an unsigned int).  log_3(2^31) is 19, so you'd only need three AVX2 vectors of powers.  Or log_4(2^31) is 15.5 so you'd only need 2 vectors to hold every non-overflowing power.

That only handles 1 input element per vector instead of 4 doubles, but it's probably faster than your current FP attempt, as well as fixing the correctness problems.  I could see that running more than 4x the throughput per iteration of what you're doing now, or even 8x, so it should be good for speed.  And of course has the advantage that correctness is possible!!

Speed gets even better for bases of 4 or greater, only 2x compare/sub per input element, or 1x for bases of 16 or greater.  (<= 8 elements to compare against can fit in one vector).

---

Implementation mistakes in the attempt to vectorize this probably-unfixable algorithm:

- `_mm256_rem_epi32` is slow library function, but you're using it with a constant divisor of 2!  Integer mod 2 is just `n & 1` for non-negative. Or if you need to handle negative remainders, you can use the tricks compilers use to implement `int % 2`: https://godbolt.org/z/b89eWqEzK where it shifts down the sign bit as a correction to do signed division.

---

#### Updated version using `(x - std::trunc(x)) < 0.000001;`

This might work, especially if you limit it to small `n`.  I'd worry that with large `n`, the difference between an exact power and off-by-1 would be a small ratio.  (I haven't really looked at the details, though.)

Your vectorization with `__m256` vectors of single-precision `float` is doomed for large `n`, but could be ok for small `n`: float32 can't represent every `int32_t`, so large odd integers (above 2^24) get rounded to multiples of 2, or multiples of 4 above 2^25, etc.

`float` has less relative precision in general, so it might not have enough to spare for this algorithm.  Or maybe there's something that could be fixed, IDK, I haven't looked closely since the update.

I'd still recommend trying a simple compare-for-equality against all possible powers in the range, broadcast-loading each element.  That will definitely work exactly, and if it's as fast then there's no need to try to fix this version using FP logs.

---

`__m256 _N_DBL = _mm256_setzero_ps();` is a confusing name; it's a vector of float, not double.  (And it's not part of a standard library header so it shouldn't be using a leading underscore.)

Also, there's zero point initializing it with zero there, since it gets written unconditionally inside the loop.  In fact it's only ever used inside the loop, so it could just be declared at that scope, when you're ready to give it a value.  Only declare variables in outer scopes if you need them after a loop.